# What's the bound of the following recurrence?

Tags: recursion

Given the following recurrence:

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + n^2
```

How can I prove it to be O(n^3) with the substitution method? The O(n^3) guess derives from the fact that at every step of the recursion we pay `n^2` and we have n steps of recursion therefore having: `n * n^2` = `n*3`.

I would even expect this to be theta(n^3), but I can't even prove O(n^3).

I tried with the guess:

```
T(n) <= n^3 + n^2 * c1 + n * c2 + c3
```

but that yields:

```
T(n) <= n^3 + n^2 * (3 + c1) + n * (c2 - 2c1 -1) + (c1 - 1 - c2 + c3)
```

which yields:

1. `c1 = c1 + c`
2. `c2 = c2 - 2c1 - 1`
3. `c3 = c1 - 1 - c2 + c3`

But even from the very first (`c1 = c1 + c`) we find that no `c1`, `c2` or `c3` satisfy the equations.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: This question would be more appropriate at [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/). If you ask there please [search for similar questions first](http://cs.stackexchange.com/search) and read their [help center](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help) before asking. Also, delete this question since [cross-posting is not advised](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/255171).

Comment: @Snowman Isn't this a conceptual question about software development? Should I modify my question so that I invent an algorithm for this recurrence and then it becomes a question about software development?

Comment: What about [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/271974/22402) question?

Comment: this is a math question that reminds me of my Algorithms class from years ago. Recurrence relations are actually a Linear Algebra concept, although they are used in Computer Science as well. Regardless, I have never seen them used in actual software, only in the classroom and in research papers. You will get a _much_ better response at the Computer Science SE site than you will here.

Comment: @Snowman It looks to me like SO, programmers.SE, math.SE and CS.SE kind of have overlapping topics. For example, should this be posted under math.SE or CS.SE?

Comment: That other question you linked would be better there too: while we do have some Big-Oh questions here, many of them are from before CS.SE existed. The rule of thumb is if you are talking algorithms _for software you are writing_ then they _probably_ belong here: if it is a more mathy academic exercise, ask at CS.SE. [This meta-answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/255171) has more info.

Comment: Yes, there is some overlap, but I am telling you as a veteran user of this site who is familiar with many of the tech/CS sites that this question will get the best responses at CS.SE.

Comment: recommended reading: **[Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773)**